# In case of repeating a preposition, can we omit one?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, ellipsis, coordination

I am trying to figure out an idea of mine as follows,

> Being the strategy of corresponding candidate matching is to intersect
>   viewing ray planes belonging to the two images at a time, specific
>   constraints are needed ***for*** the rejection of fault matching and
>   also ***for*** the reaching of optimal construction (i.e. 3D lines).

My question is, I want to say that I need constraints for two things

- the rejection of fault matching, and
- the reaching of optimal construction
  (i.e. 3D lines).

> If these two things are written as shown in my sentence, then

1. should I need to use **for** for explaning both requrements?
2. Also, should the second phrase be follow the same structure as first phrase? 
   (that mean: **for** something **of** something)

Comment: I now wonder what if we could say something like : for the rejection of **both** fault matching **and** optimal construction? I am not sure, though.

Comment: @Hakan I agree. *Both ... and* alerts the reader from the outset that two terms will be introduced, while *and also* comes in as an afterthought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reverse order:

(2) Yes, the two phrases should follow the same structure. This is not required, but it helps the reader navigate a complex sentence.

(1) Yes, you should employ the preposition in both places. Since you have parallel constructions the second may be omitted; but retaining it, again, helps the reader follow your structure.

Some additional considerations:

(a) *Being* won't work at the beginning. *Being **as*** is acceptable colloquially, but not formally. Use *since* or *because*: *Because the strategy is ...*

(b) The entire VP *to intersect ... at a time* is very unclear. I suspect what you mean is *to intersect **the** viewing ray planes which at any given time belong to the two images*.

(c) *rejection* and *reaching* are not strictly parallel: one is a derived noun and the other a gerund. Neither is satisfactory. You may write this more economically with infinitives (which permit you to drop the *for* altogether): *...are needed both to reject fault matching and to reach optimal construction.*

(d) *reject fault matching* sounds odd, but that may be my ignorance of the subject.

(e) *reach optimal construction* should probably be ***achieve*** optimal construction.

Comment: many thanks for the clear explanation. And also for very constructive suggestions to improve my way of writing. thanks many times again..

Comment: PS: ... *intersect viewing ray planes belonging to two images **at a time**...* In here, at a time mean, I take two planes and intersect, after intersecting these two, take another two planes and do the same, and again and again do the same until I get a correct outcome. The main thing is I use only TWO  planes for **each processing**. With this idea, I hope I could use "at a time" and would be understandable for others? is that please?

Comment: @niro Ah! The problem is that *at a time* here is so distant from the *two* it modifies that the sense is lost. How about this? -"Since the strategy is to intersect successive pairs of viewing planes, one from each image, ..."